# How do I use bugzilla's webservice xml-rpc with python?

Tags: python, scripting, xml-rpc, bugzilla

I need to know how to log into bugzilla using python. I have no idea where to start. The only requirement I got is that I have to use bugzilla's webservice xml-rpc. I also have no experience with python. So could anyone tell me the basic steps I need to take to import bugzilla using python? Thanks.

I have python installed on linux and can run code like `print "hello world!"`. But I did not download any additional plugins.

Do I need this plugin: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-bugzilla/1.1.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured it out:

```
bz = bugzilla.Bugzilla(url='https://bugzilla.redhat.com/xmlrpc.cgi')
bug = bz.getbug(495561)
```